# Proof of a theorem in Topology

Tags: general-topology

So, I am interested in how to proove the following theorem:

Theorem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces which are countable of first type(so, that every point has a finite local basis) and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous, then it holds that for every array $x_n$ which converges to x, it holds that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: You probably mean countable local base? Such a space is called first countable. And array = sequence, probably.

Comment: Yeahm I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No need for first countability here: if $O$ is an open set that contains $f(x)$, then $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$, by continuity, contains $x$, so contains all but finitely many $x_n$, and this means that $O$ contains all but finitely many $f(x_n)$. So $(f(x_n)) \rightarrow f(x)$.

The proof that the sequence convergence condition implies continuity does use first countability.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Helped me....

Answer (score 0):

if $f(x_n)\not \to f(x)$there is an open set $U$ such that $f(x)\in U$ but for all n,$f(x_n)\not \in U$and we have $x_n\in f^{-1}(f(x_n))\subset f^{-1}(U)$but $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set containing x so $x_n \not\to x$